# Incluir outro arquivo HTML em um arquivo HTML

Tags: jquery, html, html5

**Cenário:**
Estou montando um layout, que será utilizado por terceiros e não sei qual será a linguagem utilizada. Tenho duas divs, um será o menu esquerdo e outro o conteúdo. Eles são separados por um [Splitter](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxsplitter/index.htm#demos/jqxsplitter/defaultfunctionality.htm), minhas dúvidas são:

1. Esse menu esquerdo, quero desenvolver um `html` a parte e chama-lo
   por `include`, qual a melhor forma de fazer?
2. Se eu fizer chamada via javascript será que terei problemas com
   javascript contido nessa página que será inserida?
3. Existe algum padrão desse tipo no **HTML5**, **CSS** ou alguma forma
   simples de implementar em **JavaScript**?

---

Sei que **iframe** não é uma boa solução. Através de `<object type="text/html" data="include.html"></object>`, funciona mas creio que não seja uma boa solução também.

Comment: Provavelmente seria bom você fazer tudo separado, mas juntar num modelo pra entregar, com comments para o programador <!-- inicio do conteudo do menu.htm - trocar por include -->... ai poe o html do menu.htm...<!-- fim do conteudo do menu.htm -->, creio que seja mais simples. Aí o cliente ve funcionando, e o programador troca depois. (ou seja, forneça tudo separado, e mais um arquivo mesclado de demonstração)

Comment: exato, estou com medo de fazer algo para tentar separar e no final ficar tudo confuso.. tipo fazer um gigante código js para chamar os includes..vai achar q é necessário..enfim.. gostaria de saber se já existe algo em html5 pesquisei e não achei nada que funcione!

Comment: E tem outra, dessa forma que eu disse, você pode desenvolver no seu ambiente usando os includes da sua linguagem, (basta por os comments que eu mencionei em cima e embaixo de cada include), e na hora de entregar pro cliente você salva o source do browser mesmo como "arquivomontado.html" e entrega junto. Aí ele se vira (claro, se voce puder, explique pro programador o que fez).

Comment: Não sei se realmente as respostas estão "desatualizadas", mas realmente não tem nenhuma completa, que fale de múltiplas maneiras de resolver o problema. Infelizmente ando sem tempo pra complementar a minha – e parece que o pessoal anda votando cegamente nela porque está no topo...

Comment: @bfavaretto a sua opção é bem clara e eficiente, desde que tenha um webserver com recurso de server-side... porém como você falou, estou vendo se existem outras opções atualizadas...etc

Comment: @Dorathoto podes explicar o que queres dizer com _"devido às recentes alterações"_?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Se você estiver usando um webserver (por exemplo, o Apache ou o IIS), ele provavelmente suporta *Server-side includes*. Com isso você poderia usar, no HTML principal:

```
<!-- #include file="caminho-do-menu.html" -->
```

Comment: nossa esse é tão antigo e simples que tinha até me esquecido...ótimo..

Comment: Atento, mas daí não pode ser apenas HTML, terá que ser um ASP ou PHP para executar ServerSide. Pela pergunta, a solução deve ser ClientSide.

Answer (score 16):

Não sei se eu entendi direito, mas se for isso mesmo, e como você marcou a tag [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), então porque não usar o [`load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("#idElemento").load('xpto.html');
```

Se o conteúdo for estático, entretanto, é melhor processar no servidor, ver a resposta do @bfavaretto.

Comment: Outra opção *client-side* para quem não quer lidar diretamente com JavaScript (ainda está lá, mas debaixo dos panos) é o [csi.js](https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js). `<div data-include="me-inclua.html"></div>`. Dito isso também vou na resposta no bfavaretto, na maioria dos casos *server-side includes* são uma opção melhor por usarem menos banda, não fazer o cliente ter que pagar a latência de múltiplos *requests*. etc.

Comment: e sabe se ele dará muitos problemas se a pagina incluída tiver javascript? tipo conflitos etc? ou ele vai bem?

Comment: Os scripts serão executados como se estivessem na página principal... obviamente, que a ordem de execução vai variar, de acordo com quando o `load` será executado.

Comment: Além disso, o html incluido deverá ser um fragmento de html, e não um documento HTML completo, com head, body, etc.. senão seria o mesmo que adicionar tudo isso dentro da `div`... imagina: `<div><html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html></div>` o que não faz sentido.

Comment: Se não me engano tem uma forma de filtrar o que será inserido pelo load... caso o arquivo incluído seja um HTML completo... vou procurar.

Comment: Achei, é assim: `$("#idElementoDaPaginaMaster", "pagina.html #idElementoDaPaginaIncluida")`

Answer (score 5):

A forma que os desenvolvedores estão explorando são geradores que fazem isso para você. Temos alguns bons como o [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) e o [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/). Eu escolhi utilizar o Jekyll e ele me ajuda muito com uma linguagem que independente do programador, a compreensão do algoritmo fica fácil. 
Por exemplo, quanto tenho uma página inicial que tem 10 produtos, eu faço 1 modelo de como seria e um for para iterar essa repetição.

Exemplo do Jekyll:

```
<div class="produtos">
    {% for i in (1...9) %}
            <div class="product-align">
                <div class="product" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                    <img itemprop="image" class="product-image center-block" alt="imagem produto" src="assets/images/produto01.png">
                    <p class="product-title" itemprop="name">Cadeira Tulipa</p>
                    <p class="product-review" itemprop="review">Clássica criação de Pierre Paulin</p>


                    <div class="price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                    <!-- div que separa itens referente ao preço de cada produto -->
                        <p class="product-price">De: R$2,999.00</p>
                        <!-- preço original -->
                        <p class="final-product-price" itemprop="price">Por: R$2,000.</p>
                        <!-- preço com desconto -->
                        <p class="parcel-product-price">Ou até 6x de R$250,00.</p>
                        <!-- preço parcelado -->
                    </div>

                    <a href="produto.html">
                        <button class="btn-see-more" type="button">Veja mais</button>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

O Jekyll te permite enviar o HTML junto como se fosse uma espécie de "merge" de páginas e permite você enviar como eu mandei acima. Você pode enviar as 2 formas para o cliente e ele cuida de todo o resto. Essa é a forma mais indicada.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução elegante seria usar algum framework javascript como [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), [Angular](https://angular.io/) e etc..

Pois eles ja vem com uma estrutura bacana para se trabalhar de tal forma.

Uma vez que vocês precisa de ambientes diferentes na mesma página, na web moderna costumamos criar o web site com conceito de [componentização](https://tableless.com.br/web-components-introducao/). Pode ser uma solução agradável para seu problema.

## Exemplo

O melhor exemplo para isso são as referencias diretas no site da framework onde você poderá ver e ler afundo sobre o assunto

**[Comunidade Vue.js](http://www.vuejs-brasil.com.br/)**

**[Curso Vue.js parte 1: construindo Single Page Applications](https://cursos.alura.com.br/course/vue-parte1)**

**[Github Vue.js](https://github.com/vuejs)**

**[Site oficial Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)**

Comment: você poderia dar um pequeno exemplo de como funciona?

Comment: Preparei algumas referências para dar ponto de partida a partir daqui, leia sobre, entenda o conceito, faça aplicações teste que você vai pegar o jeito. Falei do vue porque eu pessoalmente prefiro, mas tem Angular e React pra dar uma olhada também