# Chamar header e footer sem misturar php no html

Tags: php, html, front-end

Como não misturar PHP no HTML?

Tenho um arquivo `header.html` - eu quero que esse arquivo seja mostrado em todas as páginas do meu site. Como faço isso sem renomear o `header.html` para `header.php` e dar um:

```
<?php

include "header.php"

?>
```

Comment: Uai amigo eh só deixar com header.html mesmo, desde que não tenha código php dentro do header... E as paginas que vão receber esse include tem que ser .php

Comment: `<?php include "header.html"; ?>`

Comment: Você quer usar o PHP para incluir um arquivo HTML, ou não quer PHP para nada? Veja se [esta outra pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12722/incluir-outro-arquivo-html-em-um-arquivo-html) esclarece sua dúvida.

Comment: Eu não quero misturar php no meu html é isso não quero ter um header.php quero um header,html, porem quero chamar o reader no meu index sem dar um include header.php, entendeu ?

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue isso utilizando `javascript`

Imaginando que seu `index.html` seja assim.

Crie no mesmo diretório do `index.html` um arquivo chamado `header.html` e `footer.html`.

**Testado no servidor `vertrigo`**.

> Você não conseguirá executar este código clicando diretamento
>   sobre o arquivo `index.html`

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>load html</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  console.log('init');
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" style="text-align:center;"></div>
<content>
    <section>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>label</label>
    <input type="text" />
 </div>
    </section>
</content>
<div id="footer" style="text-align:center;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
header.html
```

```
footer.html
```

Comment: Tem algum outro método sem utilizar js ?